# Installation of Windows 8.1 Universal App on managed device (Windows 10 Mobile) failed

Tags: win-universal-app, windows-10, windows-10-universal, windows-10-mobile, code-signing-certificate

The installation of the Windows 8.1 Universal App works on an unmanaged device with Windows 10 Mobile Preview.
During the installation on a Lumia 950 with Windows 10 Mobile, this error occurs:

*App can't be installed. There is a problem with this app. Please check the package or talk to the person from whom you received it.*

(Error was translated by me, so not every word will match the standard error message in english)

The App was created by cordova and is signed with a certificate. The AET is installed on the unmanaged and added to the MDM for the managed.

### Environment

OS: *Windows 8.1 Enterprise*

IDEs installed: *Visual Studio Community 2013 & 2015*

IDE used: *Visual Studio Community 2015*

VS Project details: *Apache Cordova, WinJS, angularjs*

Certificate: *Company certificate from symantec, received from extern company*

Answer (score 0):

Problem will be that Windows 8.1 application isn't really universal and you couldn't run it directly on Win10 without modifications.

[Migrate apps to the Universal Windows Platform (UWP)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt148501.aspx#MigrateCSharp)

Comment: Hm ok, but why the installation on a Windows 10 Mobile Preview works?And why there is a Windows 8.1 project created by vs cordova build and configured "Target Windows Version: Windows 10.0"?